# ASP.NET Crystal Reports without installation (DLLs only)?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports-xi

This question has probably been asked before. If it has, please add the link below and close my question.

I'm writing an ASP.NET 2.0 website where I run a crystal report, export it, and display the export to the user (note: I am NOT using the viewer control). So all I need to be able to do is load the report, set its datasource, edit the formulas/parameters, and run to an export file. Problem is, these crystal reports were written in a newer version than the one I have (the reports are crystal 11, I'm on crystal for VS2005).

I'm wondering if I can just grab some crystal 11 DLLs and reference them in my website rather than referencing the GAC DLLs or installing crystal on the deployment server. Is this possible?

I've heard of one guy doing it here http://forums.asp.net/post/585678.aspx.

When I tried, it started to complain about COM objects... Thanks!

(Edit: By the way, where are the legacy runtime downloads on SAP's website? I could only find the latest version...)